# Error switching viewcontroller from viewcontroller (with mapview) to any other view controller

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I am developing an IPS using location service on iOS. I used storyboard to design my viewControllers. There is a problem when I click on the navigation viewcontroller (which display your current location using iphonelocation service). Whichever page (Main view controller, appointment view controller, etc) that I would like to go from navigation view controller, the whole app crashes. Would like to seek help in resolving this issue, totally lost after trying for 3 days.

```
//  MenuViewController.m
@implementation MenuViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.slidingViewController setAnchorRightRevealAmount:280.0f];
  self.slidingViewController.underLeftWidthLayout = ECFullWidth;
}

-(void)goToPage:(NSString*) page
{
    UIViewController *newTopViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:page];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:newTopViewController animated:YES];
    [self.slidingViewController anchorTopViewOffScreenTo:ECRight animations:nil onComplete:^{
        CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
        self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
        [self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
    }];
}

- (IBAction)goToMainMenu:(id)sender
{
    [self goToPage:@"MenuMain"];
}

- (IBAction)goToAppointment:(id)sender
{
    [self goToPage:@"Appointment"];
}

- (IBAction)goToFindADoctor:(id)sender
{
    [self goToPage:@"FindADoctor"];
}

- (IBAction)goToNavigation:(id)sender
{
    [self goToPage:@"Navigation"];
}

- (IBAction)goToViewQueue:(id)sender
{
    [self goToPage:@"ViewQueue"];
}

@end
```

Error trace:

```
ibobjc.A.dylib`objc_msgSend:
0x177a08c:  movl   8(%esp), %ecx
0x177a090:  movl   4(%esp), %eax
0x177a094:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x177a096:  je     0x177a0e8                 ; objc_msgSend + 92
0x177a098:  movl   (%eax), %edx
0x177a09a:  pushl  %edi
0x177a09b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi
0x177a09e:  pushl  %esi  ******* Error msg (Thread 1 Exc_bad_access (code=1,address=01x7412ab...)
0x177a09f:  movl   (%edi), %esi
0x177a0a1:  movl   %ecx, %edx
0x177a0a3:  shrl   $2, %edx
0x177a0a6:  andl   %esi, %edx
0x177a0a8:  movl   8(%edi,%edx,4), %eax
0x177a0ac:  testl  %eax, %eax
0x177a0ae:  je     0x177a0b9                 ; objc_msgSend + 45
0x177a0b0:  cmpl   (%eax), %ecx
0x177a0b2:  je     0x177a0d0                 ; objc_msgSend + 68
0x177a0b4:  addl   $1, %edx
0x177a0b7:  jmp    0x177a0a6                 ; objc_msgSend + 26
0x177a0b9:  popl   %esi
0x177a0ba:  popl
```

Comment: Not an Xcode question, more of an iOS one.